# Is there a way in Google sheet to add two functions in the same cell? (Counting days)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've been trying to count the work days that have pass from "write up report date (Column M)" until "Date Received (Column Q)". If "Column Q" is blank, I would like to use today's date.

Is is possible to put together the functions so the work days can be calculated if I have an end date or if the end date is blank?

Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td4Hc.png)

So far I've been working on two different options for the "Days waiting for the report (Column O)" but I'd like to put them together in a formula.

This function count the workdays when I have the start date and end date (Example row 3 to 9):

```
=if(and(isdate(M3)+1,isdate(Q3)),NETWORKDAYS.INTL((M3),Q3,1),)
```

This function count the days when the end date is blank (Example row 10):

```
=IF(M10="","",IF(M10<TODAY(),DATEDIF(M10,TODAY(),"MD")))
```

Comment: If you are using Googlesheets, why tag Excel? They are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get the days between two dates in one situation, and then the workdays in between two dates in another situation. This can be solved using another `IF()` statement:

```
=if(work_days = TRUE,
    NETWORKDAYS(start_date, 
                if(end_date = "", TODAY(), end_date)), 
    DAYS(if(end_date = "", TODAY(), end_date), 
          start_date))
```

I created it as a named function within Google Sheets. You can see it in action [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LhKFRFcbtxD7uDGVgVMkWFgjmAAA_kU9QY7HOPwJ6S4/edit?usp=sharing).

If the code is confusing (which is fair enough!), then one option is creating a named function which just handles the first function you want to call, a second for the second function, and then a third, which asks which function you want to call, and then calls that.

Answer (score 0):

As I far as I understand, you may be able to combine these two scenarios, just by inserting the if statement inside NETWORKDAYS:

```
=if(isdate(Q3),NETWORKDAYS.INTL(IF(ISDATE(M3),M3+1,TODAY()),Q3,1),)
```

When Q3 is a date, it will calculate Network Days either with M3 or with Today's date

If you want it as an array, you can delete all column and use MAP to expand:

```
=MAP(Q3:Q,M3:M,LAMBDA(start,end,if(isdate(start),NETWORKDAYS.INTL(IF(ISDATE(end),end+1,TODAY()),start,1),)
```